# CLISP Recursive function returning at ATOM if it is a MEMBER of a list

Tags: recursion, common-lisp

I need help figuring out what I have wrong with my code, this is the problem assigned:

write a recursive function named MYMEMBER that takes an ATOM (atm) and a LIST (lst) and returns the ATOM if it is a MEMBER, otherwise NIL

ex. `(MYMEMBER ‘D ‘(A B C D E F G) returns => D`

ex. `(MYMEMBER ‘H ‘(A B C D E F G) returns => NIL`

This is what I have:

```lisp
(defun mymember (atm lst)
  (cond ((null lst) nil)
   ((equal atm (car lst)) lst)
   (t (mymember atm (cdr lst)))))
```

Mine returns:

```lisp
(mymember 'd '(a b c d e f g))
; ==> (D E F G)
```

How do I fix it so it only returns the D, instead of return the rest of the list?

Comment: Style/readability: add hyphens, don't abbreviate words, newline after cond ("mymember" => "my-member", "atm" => "atom", "lst" => "list")

Comment: You can create two different strings that both have the characters "foo". They will be EQUAL even though they are not the same string. To test if one "foo" is really in a list, you cannot use EQUAL because it would recognize the other one. I recommend EQL. (The alternative EQ would not work for numbers and characters.)

Comment: You have a really simple/easy bug, just stare at it and if necessary hand-execute with pencil and paper. There is nothing special about Lisp here.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the first term in the `cond` where you compare the atom to the first element of the list. You return `lst` if it matches. Do you think `lst`, that you already have taken `car` of, is an atom?